# Use PyCharm inspection from command line script

Tags: python, intellij-idea, command-line, continuous-integration, pycharm

I want to incorporate `PyCharm CE`'s code-inspection functionality into my continuous-integration server setup.

For that purpose I would need to call the IDE from the command-line, let it load the project, analyse  and have it dump the warnings to stdout or to a file. I imagine something similar to how `pylint` already works.

Is something like this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there is a script named `inspect.sh` bundled with `IntelliJ` (didn't check `PyCharm`) which can be used from the command line.

Note that there can only be one running instance at a time, so if you want to use this in an automated way, you'll have to run it on another machine.

Relevant [documentation can be found here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-intellij-idea-features-from-command-line.html).

Comment: Yes, `inspect.sh` is present in the PyCharm as well (5.0.2 Pro at least). On linux it's in PyCharm's `bin` dir. Cool.

Comment: PyCharm specific relevant doc: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/working-with-pycharm-features-from-command-line.html